# Minitoc doesn't work after I add Preface to Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

For my thesis, I am working with a few chapters separately and I am including these chapters in my main `.tex` file. I have defined my Preface with `\chapter*{Preface}`. In order to add the Preface to Table of Contents I have used `\addcontentsline`. For the header I have used `\chaptermark`.

```
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chaptermark{Preface}
```

This worked perfectly until I realized that my mini table of contents of other chapters are no longer appearing after I compiled. I have compiled several times no change. What can I do to make them appear while I have my Preface in the Table of Contents with the correct header.

```
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\dominitoc

\pagenumbering{roman}

\cleardoublepage

\parskip=2ex

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlepage}


\chapter{Dedication/dedication}
\chapter{Declaration/declaration}
\chapter{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\chapter{Abstract/abstract}


\tableofcontents
\printnomenclature

\mainmatter
\chapter{Preface/preface}
\adjustmtc[0]
\chapter{Chapter1/chapter1}
\chapter{Chapter2/chapter2}
\backmatter
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

I would be glad if anyone helps in this issue.

Edit: Here I simplified my code to make a working example. Honestly, I don't know if `minitoc` works in `report` class since when I comment the Preface part `minitoc` doesn't work in any case. (Normally I do use a class for thesis and `minitoc` works if I don't add the Preface in the Table of Contents.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\chapter*{Dedication}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chaptermark{Preface}
\adjustmtc[0]
\chapter{Chapter 1}
We will have two sections here.
\section{AA}
Here, I have my first section.
\section{BB}
This is my second section.
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{CC}
This is the CC section.
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\section{DD}
This is the DD section.
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document is not compilable, so nobody will be able to test the issue easily. Check the faq in the documentation "2.30 Useful precautions with starred sectionning commands".

Comment: Thanks! I made simplified my code but I am not sure if it will help since I had to change the class in order to make a working example.

Comment: Did you check the faq?

Comment: Yeap I just tried \mtcaddchapter[Preface] instead of \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface} and it seems it is working. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @physicienne: None of your code given here uses the `\minitoc` command (unless it is in the several local files you `\include`)

Answer (score 2):

Explicit `\addcontentsline` statements for starred structure units confuse the counting and the several minitoc auxiliary files. This is why `\addstarredchapter` exists:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\chapter*{Dedication}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addstarredchapter{Preface}
\chaptermark{Preface}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\minitoc
We will have two sections here.
\section{AA}
Here, I have my first section.
\section{BB}
This is my second section.
\chapter{Chapter2}
\minitoc
\section{CC}
This is the CC section.
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\minitoc
\section{DD}
This is the DD section.
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addstarredchapter` still working June 2017!

Comment: @s.k: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant the solution is still working. Instead of `\addcontentsline`. I had the same issue with minitoc that doesn't show up with starred chapter in a report.

Comment: @s.k: Since neither `minitoc` nor `report` class really changed, there is no reason why it should not work any longer ;-)